# "The prevalence of both X & Y increased with age, and * especially high in subgroup." Was/were?

Tags: verbs, grammatical-number

> The prevalence of both diabetes and obesity increased with age, and *
>   especially high in ≥65-year-olds.

Should * be was/were?

A professional language checker left my usage of "were" in one instance, but changed it to "was" in another.

The google wildcard searches:

> "the prevalence of both * was high"

and

> "the prevalence of both * were high"

both give a couple of examples, but it does not seem conclusive.

Comment: The sample sentence has a comma problem. You can drop the comma and use *and was* or retain the comma and add a subject to the second clause. The subject you choose will determine what verb to use.  I'd probably refer to *rates* instead of *prevalence* if I wanted to regard them separately. That would also clear up the verb choice.

Comment: "The prevalence of both diabetes and obesity increased with age, and rates were especially high in ≥65-year-olds." Thanks, this keeps the original structure, but seems more correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a tricky question, because *prevalence* is an uncountable noun. Consider what happens with a countable noun. In that case, the verb has to agree with the subject.

> The speed of the race car and the motorcycle was too high for me to recognize the drivers.
>   The speeds of the race car and the motorcycle were too high for me to recognize the drivers.

You could use the singular *speed* if they were going the same speed, but if they are going two different speeds, you have to use the plural.

For the OP's question, presumably diabetes and obesity each have a different prevalence, so you need the plural:

> The prevalence of both diabetes and obesity increased with age, and were especially high in ≥65-year-olds.

To show that you can't always use the singular in cases like this, consider a slightly altered question:

> *The prevalence of obesity and malnutrition is anticorrelated.
>   The prevalence of obesity and malnutrition are anticorrelated.

Here, it's clear you need to use *"are"*.

Comment: This seems well-argued, so I changed the accepted answer to this one. Sorry if it seems like I am rushing to accept answers. If anyone wants to refute this answer with logic or examples, I will consider changing the accepted answer. I would normally follow votes, but there seems to be no consensus here.

Comment: I actually think the best solution is the one in your comment: use *rates* instead of *prevalence* for the second part. I have no idea whether any grammatical authorities have considered this question, but this is my intuition as a native English speaker.

Comment: @Peter Shor BTW, where do you get that *prevalence* is an uncountable noun? *Prevalences* is well established in exactly this sense. [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prevalences&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprevalences%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @Phil: According to the dictionary, [prevalance](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/prevalence) is uncountable. And look at the [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prevalences%2C+prevalence&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprevalences%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprevalence%3B%2Cc0) comparing the frequencies of *prevalence* and *prevalences*. If *prevalence* were countable, *prevalences* would be much more common.

Comment: @PeterShor I see, but like many uncountable nouns, it sometimes has a plural form, and the OP's Q  could be written as "The prevalence**s** of both diabetes and obesity increased with age and *were* especially high in ≥65-year-olds."

Comment: ... and that's possibly the best answer. Some people are definitely using it.

Answer (score 2):

**Apology**

To my intense embarassment I have to say that this accepted answer is *not* correct for the sentence “The prevalence of both...”. The subject is prevalence, singular, and therefore the verb must be the singular, ‘was’. I offer my profound apologies.

**Answer to a different question**

If the sentence had been “Both diabetes and obesity increased with age...” the verb would be the plural, ‘were’.

The ‘and’ in ‘Both X and Y’ makes it clear that ‘both’ has a plural subject and requires a plural verb in normal usage.

**Supporting Sources**

I would not have thought it necessary to provide citations to support my statement that ‘both’ requires a plural verb with a plural subject. This seems uncontentious as it is not even treated under the entries for ‘both’ in Gower (‘The Complete plain words’ and ‘English Modern Usage’) or by Fowler and Fowler in ‘The King’s English’). However, as I have been asked for citations, here they are:

> “And they *were* *both* naked, the man and his wife, and *were* not
>   ashamed.”
>
> Genesis 2:25 (KJV)
>
> “The Douglas and the Hotspur *both* together *Are* confident against the
>   world in arms.”
>
> Shakespeare, Henry IV, Part I [V, 1]
>
> For both were faiths and *both* *have* gone.
>
> Mathew Arnold “The Grand Chartreuse”

That said, I must admit that Shakespeare is (as ever) not consistent. Thus:

> Nay, come, I pray you, sir, give me the chain:
>
> *Both* wind and tide *stays* for this gentleman,
>
> Shakespeare, Comedy of Errors [IV, 1]

But this strikes one immediately as archaic.

Comment: So the usage of "and" precludes seeing the nouns as non-quantitative?

Comment: @CarlAH — I wouldn't know. All I'm saying is when I rephrase it with the 'and' only the plural sounds like English. Like 'Jack and Jill go up the hill'. I couldn't imagine 'goes'.

Comment: @David Purely opinion based answers aren't good enough. Can you cite a rule or quote a reputable source? *Both* may very well be plural, but what does that have to do with determining the tense of the verb? It's either not the subject, or not even in the same clause, depending on how the comma problem gets resolved.

Comment: @PhilSweet — Hadn't realized I'd strayed into a parallel universe where one had to cite the milk that one imbibed at one's mother's breast. But as I'm new here...

Comment: Aren't we talking about the prevelance, singular, and therefore shouldn't we use "was", ie "The prevalence of both X & Y was high."

Comment: OK I missed that on my phone. Was just looking at the snippet. I withdraw my answer.

Comment: Seems I can't delete an accepted answer. Oh dear. I'll see if I can edit it.

Comment: II have edited my answer so that it is now a right answer to a wrong question. It would be better deleted completely. Perhaps an admin user can do this. Failing that, downvote it. Sorry for the muckup.

Answer (score 0):

Was.

The verb agrees with the singular "prevalence", not with "X and Y". So "X and Y **were** highly prevalent", but "the prevalence ... **was** high".

Comment: So would you say: *"The prevalence of obesity and malnutrition is anticorrelated"*?